# codeigniter and mysql update error?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

when i try to update a table i get an error that time.
[image: error image]

there is my controller code.

```
$this->hr_user->insert_user($info);

        $n=explode('--', $info['user_code']);
        $temp=$n[1];
        $lnum=ltrim($temp,'0');
        //print_r($lnum);
        //echo "<br>lastnumber".$lnum;
        $id=$info['user_type'];
        echo $id.''.$lnum;



        $this->hr_user->update_number($id,$lnum);



        redirect('hrm/index');
```

and here is my model code.

```
public function update_number($id,$lnum)
{
    $this->db->where('em_id',$id);
    $this->db->update('tbl_emaster.em_lastnumber',$lnum);

}
```

Comment: have you tried any of these answers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mysql error you got explains every thing. Your query order doesn't generate a qualified query, try:

```
public function update_number($id,$lnum)
{
    $this->db->set('eenter code herem_lastnumber', '$lnum');
    $this->db->where('em_id',$id);
    $this->db->update('emaster');
}
```

for more info [www.codeigniter.com](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#updating-data)

Answer (score 3):

```
$this->db->set('field', 'field+1');
$this->db->where('id', 2);
$this->db->update('mytable'); 
// gives UPDATE `mytable` SET `field` = '   field+1' WHERE `id` = 2
```

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#updating-data

Answer (score 1):

Mysql update query syntax is :

```
UPDATE table_name SET field1 = new-value1, field2 = new-value2
[WHERE Clause]
```

You can see, there are fields after `SET`.
And because of your CI update syntax, column name is not being passed. And to pass that, you should pass array as 2nd argument of `$this->db->update('tbl_emaster.em_lastnumber',$lnum);`

So you need to change it like this:

```
$this->db->update('tbl_emaster',array('em_lastnumber' => $lnum);
```

Answer (score 1):

change query

```
public function update_number($id,$lnum)
{
    $data=array('em_lastnumber'=>$lnum);
    $this->db->where('em_id',$id);
    $this->db->update('tbl_emaster',$data);

}
```